# Partial View redirects instead of populating div

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to set up a relationship where you click on a PO in grid 1 and grid 2 will show with related items.  I have been researching and have tried several different methods. My current link is:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "DisplayPOItems", new { id = Model.poList[0].ID }, new AjaxOptions
{
     UpdateTargetId = "POItems",
     HttpMethod = "GET",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
})
```

I have also tried just an action link with this:

```
$("#POSelect").click(function () {
     $.get('@Url.Action("DisplayPOItems","PO", new { id = Model.ID })', function () {
     $('#POItems').load(this.href);
     return false;
     });
});
```

OR a similar block using ajax to catch the click event and try to populate the partial view into a div on my form that way.  All of these methods have populated data but it always redirects to .../PO/DisplayPOItems/1 and shows only the partial view there.  Here is my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult DisplayPOItems(int ID)
{
     ItemModel im = new ItemModel();
     return PartialView("_GridItem", im.POSearchResult(ID));
}
```

I have tried ActionResult on the Controller also but it didn't help.  How can I get the page to not redirect and just populate the div on my form with my partial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to use a `Ajax.ActionLink` make sure you have referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And if you decide to use normal jQuery make sure that you are sending a single AJAX request instead of two as you currently do. Also make sure that you are returning false at the correct place:

```
$('#POSelect').click(function () {
     var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayPOItems", "PO", new { id = Model.ID })';
     $.get('url', function (result) {
         $('#POItems').html(result);
     });
     return false;
});
```

or it's equivalent:

```
$('#POSelect').click(function () {
     var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayPOItems", "PO", new { id = Model.ID })';
     $('#POItems').load(url);
     return false;
});
```

or if you link already contains the correct url:

```
$('#POSelect').click(function () {
     $('#POItems').load(this.href);
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Unobtrusive fixed it.  Been fighting with this for a while.  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

I was dealing with same problem couple of days back, I just wanted to add to above answers and is by using AJAX.

you need to have two java scripts running in the main view page where you want to render other partial views. only using unobstrusive-ajax dint help in my application.

here are the scripts.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

your view page also requires this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
    {
```

target id will be in div tag

```
<div id="results">
@renderpartial("results")
</div>
```

This can help to get the content without reloading the entire page. but I'm facing a problem with this. I can't actually redirect to another View(redirect to other controller action and get to its View) but the partial page load works fine. I mean control goes there but gets back to the same view instead of moving to other view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding script tag helped, this could be Bundled in configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have a jQuery plugin for this sort of thing.

```
$ ->
    $.fn.LoadViewInline = (url,target,useInline,callback) ->
        #debugger
        $.disableEventPropagation(event);
        if(!url)
            url = $(this).data("inline-url")
        if(!useInline)
            useInline = $(this).data("inline")
        if useInline == "True" or useInline == true 
            if(!target)
                target = $(this).data "inline-target"
            if(!targetSelectorPrefix)
                targetSelectorPrefix = "#"
            $(targetSelectorPrefix + target).load url, callback
        else
            window.location.href = url
        return false
```

Used something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a Claimant", "Index", "Property", 
    new RouteValues().With("fnolid", Fnolid),
    HtmlValues.WithClass("header")
    .Data("inline-url", dataInlineNewClaimantUrl)
    .Data("inline-target", dataInlineTarget)
    .Data("inline", dataInline)
    .With("onclick", "return $(this).LoadViewInline();")
```

Comment: I was wondering what I had been doing wrong with the jQuery.  Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @MattBodily I posted the Coffeescript source, here is the compiled javascript: http://pastebin.com/DKnEkF21